# scraping searchencrypt always redirects to expired

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Using scrapy, I am trying to scrape a searchencrypt url like this:

```
https://www.searchencrypt.com/encsearch?q=box&d=search&ps=www
```

but it always redirects to

```
https://www.searchencrypt.com/search?eq=Y8Ly0N6PX%2bPfTYAwJIXS%2bw%3d%3d&ett=5&ptc=://mail
```

It works perfectly fine in browser.

I have been tried multiple permutations of values for settings like `USER_AGENT`, `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`, `DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS` , `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`, `COOKIES_ENABLED`, `DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD`, `DNS_TIMEOUT` etc.

Are you aware of any working settings or option in scrapy that I can use to prevent this from redirecting?

Comment: when I try first url in browser then it redirect me to url similar to second url. Maybe you make something else when you run in your browser.

Comment: some portals check many different elements to recognize browser and block scripts/bot. Maybe you have to set some headers in requests - ie. `User-Agent` ?

Comment: @furas Sure, I guess you are on correct lines, feel free to post answer once you have a complete answer with scrapy.

Comment: As @furas suggested, take a look at the headers you’re using, try some stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

If you clear your local storage and cookies for that domain, keep the Network inspector open in your browser, and visit the URL, you’ll see all the requests and responses that happen until your web browsers shows the content.

Find the request that contains the actual data you want, check out all its headers, find out how they are built (e.g. from data received from previous requests that you would have to run before that final request), and try and emulate that workflow for a single search URL.